# ListBox inside a ListBoxItem template

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, .net-4.5

I have a ListBox with the following ItemTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate>
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock .... />
    <ListBox .... />
  </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

I would like to forbid the user to Select an item in a child ListBox, and that when user clicks on the child ListBox, a parent ListBox SelectedItem should be set respectively.

What I have tried is to set IsHitTestVisible of the child ListBox to false, and that prevents the user to select an item on it, but the problem is that if I click on the child ListBox, the mouse click is not passed to parent ListBoxItem, so it never gets selected.

So to summarize, I need:

- prevent the user to select item on the child listbox.
- item on the parent listbox should be selected when we click anywhere in the ItemTemplate area (even when clicked on Child listbox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace the inner `ListBox` with an `ItemsControl`. Based on your question, it sounds like you just need to display a collection, and prevent the user from interacting with it. A simple `ItemsControl` is well suited for that.
The `ItemsControl` does not support selection, so the click will get propagated up to your main `ListBox`.

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, I'd recommend trying one of two options. First, you could set `IsHitTestVisible` to false on the list box items, as in the following example

```
<!-- XAML for the inner list box -->
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.Resources>
       <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
          <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False" />
       </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

This will cause the click event to propagate up to your main list box, while still being able to use a list box.

Second, maybe it would be easier to just create two separate list boxes? Again, you haven't fully explained why this is required, but trying to load up one control with different modes of functionality sometimes overcomplicates things. Having two controls, and showing only one at a time based on some condition, can be an easy way to simplify the XAML.

Comment: I cannot use ItemsControl, because it is more complicated than I explained. Basically this child ListBox has two modes: one is non-selectable, and nother is selectable. In these two modes child ListBox is having different Panels for ItemsPanel. I did not want to go too much into specifics, because that would make things much more complicated. For this reason I was specific to ask how to achieve this using ListBox.

Comment: @Goran, Interesting. I'll do some experimenting. Could you edit your question to include a few of the details behind changing the `ItemsPanel`, whether you're using an MVVM approach, any other pertinent details?

Comment: @Goran, updated my answer. Please comment on whether this helps get you closer to a solution.